# Possible malfunction in tagging feature

Tags: bug, comment-replies

See the last comment on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589703/two-algorithms-for-the-jacobi-method-why-the-time-change) and the comments on [this Math SX question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901106/prove-or-disprove-that-there-exists-a-unique-positive-integer-sequence-a-n) for more details. In those two cases, I tried to tag a user and the tag just vanished. Now I don't know if that is normal at the start of a comment or with those users, or both, or if it's a malfunction, but I wanted to report this and ask if it was or not a bug in the @-tagging function. And since it was from two different SX sites, I thought I'd ask about it on the general Meta, i.e. here, rather than on the Meta of either of those sites.

Comment: It's called comment replies, not tags. Tag is a totally different term.

Comment: This is intentional, redundant @replies are removed automatically. In these cases there is nobody else involved that could be addressed, it is clear who is meant even without the @

Comment: @ShadowWizard Do you think this might be the most common by-design bug report on Meta? (Recently emerged contender: the review count indicator).

Comment: @Thursday nah, not that common. I think most users delete their question once it's closed as dupe though so we can't know the actual amounts.

Comment: But why are they removed only at comment start? If I put an @-reply in the middle of a comment, it stays there.

Comment: @MickG I guess the regular expression that SE uses for this purpose looks only at the beginning of the comment... perhaps they don't want to risk removing a piece of code from the middle of comment that happened to look like user ping.